# I don't figure out why I am getting 401 Unauthorized error in Reactjs? Why?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, token, access-token

My problem is simple, but to find a solution is my big problem.
I am trying to get a list of projects from my ASP.NET Web APi server. I secured the endpoint (my `Controller`) like this: 
`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class ProjectController : ApiController {}`
I am sending the JWT along with the request as a header to enable the secured endpoint's recognition of the logged-in user (In this case `Admin`). I am using these methods in `actions.js`:

```
function getAccessToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}

let data = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `bearer ${getAccessToken()}` }
};

export function projectsFetchData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(projectsIsLoading(true));

        fetch(url, data)
            .then((response) => {

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            dispatch(projectsIsLoading(false));
            return response;

            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((projects) => dispatch(projectsFetchDataSuccess(projects)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(projectsHasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

When I run my app and if I want to get my projects, let's say I am logged in as `Admin` I got the error message `401 (Unauthorized)`. But if I refresh the site I get the projects list! and after log out and in again as `User` I can get my list of projects!- I don't understand why all this trouble?
I tried with `Fiddler` and `Postman`and its works perfectly (Just `Admin`can see the list as desired):

```
GET     http://localhost:9300/project/
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: bearer pGuJAuZDrL....
```

Any help or suggestions is very appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: This is most likely a CORS issue. You basically need to tell your server to  set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to *

Comment: `@sisanared` `CORS` is allowed. I can get my list without a problem. The problem is when i log in as `Admin` i cannot get my list (get the `error` msg), but if i refresh the site i get my list..!!! And if i log out and in as `User` i can get my list even though i put `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`?? - I tried with `Fiddler` and it works perfectly! (get my list when i log in as `Admin` and no list when i log in as `User`)